# svelte-material-ui: Failed to load "/smui.css"

Tags: svelte, vite, sveltekit, svelte-material-ui

After upgrade `sveltekit`, which use `vite` **3.0.2**, when open page, get error:

```
Failed to load url /smui.css?direct (resolved id: /smui.css?direct).
This file is in /public and will be copied as-is during build without going through the plugin transforms, and therefore should not be imported from source code.
It can only be referenced via HTML tags.
```

Under `static/`, I can see `smui.css` and `smui-dark.css` generated, it used to work, but suddenly got above issue.

Any idea?

Link: [github issue](https://github.com/hperrin/svelte-material-ui/issues/489)

Comment: Have you read through the Vite [migration guide](https://vitejs.dev/guide/migration.html)?

Comment: @H.B. Just skimmed it, didn't find the hint, you mean `/static` -> `/public` ? I've tried that. Seems doesn't work. I'm not familiar with vite, any idea?

Comment: Well, how do you use the styles? The error states "It can only be referenced via HTML tags."

Comment: It's included in `app.html` via `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/smui.css" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)" />`, according to the smui doc: https://github.com/hperrin/svelte-material-ui/blob/master/SVELTEKIT.md

Comment: @H.B. It might be a svelte-kit bug: https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/5672

Comment: bug fixed in sveltekit `1.0.0-next.392`

Comment: Then please answer the question yourself/accept the answer or delete the question (chances of other people encountering are fairly low, if that is fixed and people might try upgrading first).

Comment: @H.B. Answer added.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sveltekit bug *(vite related)*, which was fixed in `1.0.0-next.392`.

Refer: https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/5672